# Excel видит надстройку, но при подключении пишет, что нет доступа к файлу

Tags: excel

Создал надстройку, установил ее в папку пользователю:
**C:\Documents and Settings\user\Application Data\Microsoft\AddIns**

В данной папке так же лежат другие надстройки и мои и чужие.

Запускаю Excel, захожу в надстройки, чтоб [image: подключить].
Выбираю надстройку и [image: получаю ошибку].

С надстройкой все в порядке, у остальных 100 человек работает без нареканий.

Единственное, что на данном компьютере при попытке открыть двойным кликом
[image: вылетает предупреждение].
Куда копать, чтоб понять ошибку?

Повторюсь, ошибка только на одном компьютере, одного пользователя из 100.

Comment: Возможно, на машине не установлена библиотека, необходимая для работы надстройки. Сравните установленные на разных компьютерах: в редакторе *VBA* закладка *Tools-References*

Comment: В перечне надстроек - **0.13*, а пытаетесь вызывать **0.12.xlam*

Comment: @vikttur да, версии файлов 0.12 и 0.13 - просто скриншоты разные, установленные библиотеки проверю завтра на работе, отпишусь о результате, спасибо.

Comment: @vikttur, проверил библиотеки, все корректно, может быть есть еще мысли.. первый раз за 4 года сталкиваюсь с такой ситуацией

Comment: У меня в точности такая же проблема, только с надстройкой Solver.xlam (поиск решения). Библиотека с таким же именем лежит возле неё. При запуске тоже спрашивает о каком-то восстановлении, а при подключении якобы нет доступа: сомневается в верности пути или наличии файла/ не использует ли другая программа и т.д.
Если вы решили свою проблему, подскажите как именно вы это сделали, ведь у меня аналогичная ситуация.